# Write adapter for microsoft azure in sitemap_generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, sitemap-generator-gem

I am using [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) for generating sitemaps in my RoR project.Everything is working fine till now.I am hosting my project on Heroku, which doesn't allow writing to the local filesystem.I still require some write access, because the sitemap files need to be written out before uploading. But I have to  use microsoft azure to store my sitemap.The adapters listed in sitemap_generator does not include azure.Could someone point me in the right direction for writing an adapter for azure.

Refering to  "Configure carrierwave" in [this](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku) article I have made a few changes in my code.

But I am not sure only editing the initialiazer file is going to help.In the above article Carrierwave points to the WaveAdapter [here](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/blob/master/lib/sitemap_generator/adapters/wave_adapter.rb) which uses CarrierWave::Uploader::Base to upload to any service supported by CarrierWave

## config/initializers/azure.rb

```
Azure.configure do |config|
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"
    config.storage = :microsoft_azure
    config.permissions = 0666
    config.microsoft_azure_credentials = {
       :provider               => 'azure',
       :storage_account_name      => 'your account name',
       :storage_access_key  => 'your key',
    }
    config.azure_directory  = 'container name'
end
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied my setup from [the S3 adapter](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/blob/master/lib/sitemap_generator/adapters/s3_adapter.rb) and from [Azure's ruby example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby/tree/master/blob)

Add the azure blob gem to your Gemfile:
`gem 'azure-storage-blob'`

create config/initializers/sitemap_generator/azure_adapter.rb:

```rb
require 'azure/storage/blob'

module SitemapGenerator
  # Class for uploading sitemaps to Azure blobs using azure-storage-blob gem.
  class AzureAdapter
    #
    # @option :storage_account_name [String] Your Azure access key id
    # @option :storage_access_key [String] Your Azure secret access key
    # @option :container [String]
    def initialize
      @storage_account_name = 'your account name'
      @storage_access_key = 'your key'
      @container = 'your container name (created already in Azure)'
    end

    # Call with a SitemapLocation and string data
    def write(location, raw_data)
      SitemapGenerator::FileAdapter.new.write(location, raw_data)

      credentials = {
        storage_account_name: @storage_account_name,
        storage_access_key: @storage_access_key
      }

      client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService.create(credentials)
      container = @container
      content = ::File.open(location.path, 'rb') { |file| file.read }
      client.create_block_blob(container, location.filename, content)
    end
  end
end
```

- Make sure the container you create in Azure is a 'blob' container so the container is not public but the blobs within are.

and then in config/sitemaps.rb:

```rb
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = 'https://[your-azure-address].blob.core.windows.net/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = '[your-container-name]/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::AzureAdapter.new
```

That should do it!

Comment: Wow.. That was perfect... Thank u

Comment: Also currently my sitemap is being generated in tmp folder.. But when I go to /sitemap. xml.gz path it shows an err '' No route match''... Do I have to write a route which points to that file??? Or should I write a route which downloads the file from my azure blob???

Comment: Hey @Vaishnavi in my `public/robots.txt`, I have the line
`Sitemap: https://[your-azure-address].blob.core.windows.net/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz`
That should be fine for all crawlers AFAIK.  Couldn't hurt to also have a redirect route to that location as well.

Comment: There's an extra comma(,) in the above example which throws an err "options provided are not valid ".....before initailize->@storage_access_key.........